# NoClassDefFoundError StringUtils or Gson when running a JavaFX Gradle application

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, classpath

I'm building a JavaFX application and I seem to be having trouble adding and using libraries like Gson or Apache Commons Lang. The libraries seem to add fine when referenced in my `build.gradle` and Intellij also shows they're in my project.. Gradle also seems to run `clean` and `build` with no problems. The problem occurs when I actually run the app and click the button that triggers the event sub-routine where the problem begins. I also get errors like this, no matter the library I try to reference:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
```

### Here's my code

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'
//apply plugin: 'excelsiorJet'

group 'eagleview'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

if (JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) {
    throw new GradleException("Must Build with Java 1.8")
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.4'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    //ext.jetPluginVersion = '1.1.0'

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
        //classpath "com.excelsiorjet:excelsior-jet-gradle-plugin:$jetPluginVersion"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'eagleview.App',
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),

        )
    }
}

jfx {
    // Minimal requirement for jfxJar-task
    mainClass = 'eagleview.App'

    // Minimal requirement for jfxNative-task
    vendor = 'eagleview'
}

//excelsiorJet {
//    mainClass = 'eagleview.App'
//    hideConsole = true
//}
```

ConfigurationController.java

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConfigurationController {
    private static Stage stage;

    public void render(Stage primary) throws Exception {
        stage = primary;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("views/vwConfiguration.fxml"));

        stage.setTitle ("Config - Eagle View");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAddVideoClicked(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(new SettingsModel()));

        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("What video would you like to add?");
        dialog.setContentText("Please provide a YouTube URL to add to your video list.");
        dialog.initOwner(stage);

        dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(x -> {
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(x)) {
                System.out.println(x);
                importVideoQueue.add(x);
            }
        });

        event.consume();
    }
}
```

Yields the following error when the `handleButtonAddVideoClicked` is ran:

```
mymachine$ java -jar build/libs/eagleview-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /c
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
    at eagleview.controllers.ConfigurationController.handleButtonAddVideoClicked(ConfigurationController.java:50)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 57 more
```

If I remove the Gson code I will then get an error about StringUtils that looks the exact same as above except referencing that particular library package path.

What's going on? Is my Gradle script not configured correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. I was trying to build a JAR but my current `jar` block wasn't cutting it. I needed to build a "fat" jar that dynamically pulls in the libraries. Removed the `jar` block and added the `fatJar` block below.

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'eagleview.App'

    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    } with jar
}
```

I built with `./gradlw clean fatJar` and application ran perfectly with no errors!

Answer (score 1):

You miss apache commons-lang in your classpath. Add

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang
compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '1.0.1'
```

to your gradle file.

The version 2.6 has a package name

```
org.apache.commons.lang2
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do I need to change exactly and within what block or directive? I have the `compile` directive in my `dependancies` block already. I am using version 2.6 of Apache Commons. This also occurs when I attempt to use Gson or any other library. Typically, in web applications I only need to do the initial `compile` statement and the rest is done for me and works great.

Comment: @Dan As i wrote, you need version 1.0.1 of  commons-lang not 2.6

Comment: Why would I need such an older version of that library? Also, that doesn't solve my Gson problem either. The issue isn't with Apache Commons or Gson but the fact that ANY library I attempt to add to gradle I can't seem to reference in my JavaFX code.

Comment: @Dan *Why would I need such an older version of that library* because you use a class of it. Apache has change the package name in version 2.x to commons-lang2

Comment: Let's take Apache Commons out of the situation for a moment. What about this error? `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`